# Custom Filter Class - more than one filter in class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've read a number of tutorials on custom filters.

Here is how my custom filter is set up:

```
class MyCustomFilter {

  public function filter($route, $request) {

  }

  public function filter2($route, $request) {

  }
}
```

In my filters file I have:

```
Route::filter('my_filter', 'MyCustomFilter');
```

Is there a way to have more than one filter in a class? I've tried calling it like so:

```
Route::filter('my_filter', 'MyCustomFilter.filter2');
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to achieve this by using **class@method**

```
Route::filter('my_filter', 'MyCustomFilter@filter');
Route::filter('my_filter', 'MyCustomFilter@filter2');
```